# org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: user data directoryisalready in use,

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

Hi everyone I'm using selenium web driver and java and IntelliJ, I want to open the chrome browser but I get that error every time actually the browser opens but then it stops it doesn't open the page I want. I did set up everything correctly.

Starting ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.88 (89e2380a3e36c3464b5dd1302349b1382549290d-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#1761}) on port 27139

Only local connections are allowed.

Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.

ChromeDriver was started successfully.

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver